# error: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
def reverse (lista):
    if isinstance (lista, list):
        resultado = reverse_aux (lista, -1, [])
        print (resultado)
    else:
        return "Error"


def reverse_aux (lista, contador, new_list):
    if (lista == []):
        return new_list
    else:
        return reverse_aux (lista [contador], contador -1, new_list + [lista [contador]])
```

La función trata sobre acomodar la lista al revés de forma manual sin utilizar funciones predeterminadas en python, estoy aprendiendo a programar.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que debes poner la lista de forma invertida, pero sin usar funciones predeterminadas para ello. Supongo que al menos deberías poder usar `for` o `while`. De ser así, entonces es muy sencillo

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

rev = []
for elem in lista:
    rev = [elem] + rev

print(rev) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Diría que la intención es que sea una solución recursiva

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que parece, buscas una solución *recursiva*. Ya que estás empezando, déjame que te dé algunos consejos:

Para comprobar si una lista está vacía, lo *pythónico* es comprobar su longitud: `len(lista) == 0`. Si haces `lista == []` estaría creando una lista vacía para hacer luego la comparación (Aunque en realidad no será así ya que el intérprete de python optimiza la expresión).

Vayamos con el error que te da:

En la primera iteración de la función `reverse_aux`, haces una llamada recursiva con el argumento `lista[contador]`, que sería un elemento de la lista en la posición `contador`. Lo que tienen que enviar es la lista de los elementos anteriores, algo así: `lista[:contador]`. Advierte los `':'` que indica *rango* de elementos.

Pero en cada iteracción, la lista se va acortando, por lo que el contador no está apuntando al elemento correcto. Existen dos alternativas:

No usar ningún contador. Simplemente, usar el último elemento:

```py
def reverse_aux (lista, new_list):
    if len(lista) == 0:
        return new_list
    else:
        return reverse_aux(lista[:-1], new_list + [lista[-1]])
```

No pasar la lista, para lo cuál metemos la función auxiliar dentro de la función principal:

```py
def reverse (lista):
    def reverse_aux (contador, new_list):
        if len(lista) < -contador:
            return new_list
        else:
            return reverse_aux(contador-1, new_list + [lista[contador]])

    if isinstance (lista, list):
        resultado = reverse_aux(-1, [])
        print (resultado)
    else:
        return "Error"
```

Hay que observar que la función auxiliar tiene que estar definida antes de ser invocada, por eso el cambio de posición.

Siendo *ortodoxos*, en programación funcional siempre se emplean las listas de izquierda a derecha ya que se suponen que es su forma natural de acceso. Así mismo, se pueden juntar los dos *returns* en una expresión ternaria. Esta podría ser una forma más correcta de hacer este ejercicio:

```py
def reverse (lista):

    def reverse_aux (lista, new_list):
        return new_list if len(lista) == 0 \
               else reverse_aux(lista[1:], [lista[0]] + new_list)

    if isinstance (lista, list):
        resultado = reverse_aux(lista, [])
        print (resultado)
    else:
        return "Error"
```

---

**PD**: aunque no quieras usar funciones predeterminadas, invertir una lista es tan simple como `lista[::-1]`. Advierte que hay dos `':'`.